# Posting an Array as JSON using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, arrays, json

i try to post the following array as json to my api:

```
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    module: 1,
    category: 2
},{
    id: 2,
    module: 1,
    category: 2
},{
    id: 3,
    module: 1,
    category: 2
}];
```

using:

```
Ember.$.ajax("any.url", {
    type: 'POST',
    data: { data: data },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

but instead of an array, my rails receives

Started POST "any.url" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-12-15 17:37:17 +0000
Processing by DataController#update_positions as JSON

```
Parameters: {"data"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"1", "module"=>"1", "category"=>"2"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"2", "module"=>"1", "category"=>"2"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"3", "module"=>"1", "category"=>"2"}}}
```

I expext someting like `{"data": [{ "id": ...`

what is wrong with my post-request??

Comment: you are passing an object array, maybe when you iterate the results the output is what are you printing

Comment: A few things. 1: you're missing a lot of commas in your data object. 2: you can pass in the data variable like data: data. No need for the extra object.

Comment: what do you mean? "iterate the results"?

Comment: i mean, this is what are u receiving? or are you doing a for(i=0;....

Comment: it does not matter if the array is created using var data = [...] or using a for(...) data.addObject({...})

Comment: which gem and version of json you have used?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    module: 1,
    category: 2
},{
    id: 2,
    module: 1,
    category: 2
},{
    id: 3,
    module: 1,
    category: 2
}];

Ember.$.ajax("any.url", {
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: does not work. data: data results in Parameters: {"undefined"=>""}